# TypeError: order is undefined

Tags: json, django-rest-framework, react-redux, axios

I'm very new to react-redux following this tutorial to create ecomme website ,so here's a order screen to place a payment after hitting the place order button but it is showing error saying 'order' is undefined
this is my OrderScreen.js i've tried adding order && in front of order but to no avail it return screen with no listed order items

```
import React ,{useEffect,useState}from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch,useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Row,Col,ListGroup,Image,Card,Button } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import { getOrderDetails } from '../actions/orderActions'
//import axios from 'axios'
function OrderScreen({match}) {
    const orderId=match.params.id
    const orderDetails=useSelector(state=>state.orderDetails)
    const{order,error,loading}=orderDetails

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    
    if (!loading && !error){
        order.itemsPrice=order.orderItems.reduce((acc,item)=>acc+item.price*item.qty,0).toFixed(2)

    }
    
    useEffect(()=>{
      
        if ( !order || order._id !== Number(orderId)){
            dispatch (getOrderDetails(orderId))
        }
       
    },[dispatch,order,orderId])

   
    return (
        <div>
           
            <Col md={8}>
                <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        <h2>Shipping</h2>
                        <p>
                            <strong>Shipping:</strong>
                            { order.shippingAddress.address},{ order.shippingAddress.city}
                            {' '}
                            { order.shippingAddress.postalCode},
                            {' '}
                            { order.shippingAddress.country}
                        </p>
                    </ListGroup.Item>

                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        <h2>Payment Method</h2>
                        <p>
                            <strong>Method:</strong>
                            { order.paymentMethod}
                           
                        </p>
                    </ListGroup.Item>

                    <ListGroup.Item>
                        <h2>Order Items</h2>
                       {order.orderItems.length===0 ?
                      <h3>Your order is empty</h3> 
                    :(
                        <ListGroup varaint='flush'>
                            { order.orderItems.map((item,index)=>
                                <ListGroup.Item key={index}>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Col md={2}>
                                        <Image src={item.image} alt={item.name} fluid rounded/>
                                        </Col>

                                        <Col>
                                        <Link to={`/product/${item.product}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                                        </Col>
                                        <Col md={4}>
                                            {item.qty} X ${item.price}=${(item.qty*item.price).toFixed(2)}
                                        </Col>
                                    </Row>
                                </ListGroup.Item>
                            )}
                        </ListGroup>
                    )}
                    </ListGroup.Item>
                </ListGroup>
            </Col>

            <Col md={4}>
                <Card>
                    <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                                <ListGroup.Item>
                                    <h2>Order Summary</h2>
                                </ListGroup.Item>

                                <ListGroup.Item>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Col>Item:</Col>
                                        <Col>${  order.itemsPrice}</Col>
                                    </Row>
                                </ListGroup.Item>

                                <ListGroup.Item>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Col>Shipping:</Col>
                                        <Col>${ order.shippingPrice}</Col>
                                    </Row>
                                </ListGroup.Item>

                                <ListGroup.Item>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Col>Shipping:</Col>
                                        <Col>${ order.taxPrice}</Col>
                                    </Row>
                                </ListGroup.Item>

                                <ListGroup.Item>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Col>Total:</Col>
                                        <Col>${ order.totalPrice}</Col>
                                    </Row>
                                </ListGroup.Item>


                                
                    </ListGroup>
                </Card>
            </Col>
        </div>
    )
}

export default OrderScreen
```

heres my reducer for order:

```
export const orderDetailsReducer = (state = { loading: true, orderItems: [], shippingAddress: {} }, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case ORDER_DETAILS_REQUEST:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            }

        case ORDER_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
            return {
                loading: false,
                order: action.payload
            }

        case ORDER_DETAILS_FAIL:
            return {
                loading: false,
                error: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

here's my action for order:

```
export const getOrderDetails = (id) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    try {
        dispatch({
            type: ORDER_DETAILS_REQUEST
        })

        const {
            userLogin: { userInfo },
        } = getState()

        const config = {
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`
            }
        }

        const { data } = await axios.get(
            `/api/orders/${id}/`,
            config
        )

        dispatch({
            type: ORDER_DETAILS_SUCCESS,
            payload: data
        })


    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: ORDER_DETAILS_FAIL,
            payload: error.response && error.response.data.detail
                ? error.response.data.detail
                : error.message,
        })
    }
}
```

here's my django view to get orders by id:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def getOrderById(request, pk):

    user = request.user

    try:
        order = Order.objects.get(_id=pk)
        if user.is_staff or order.user == user:
            serializer = OrderSerializer(order, many=False)
            return Response(serializer.data)
        else:
            Response({'detail': 'Not authorized to view this order'},
                     status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    except:
        return Response({'detail': 'Order does not exist'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

i've used the combine reducer to combine the remaining reducer the one that ive used in this que is :

```
orderDetails: orderDetailsReducer,
```

constants i've used for state:

```
export const ORDER_DETAILS_REQUEST = 'ORDER_DETAILS_REQUEST'
export const ORDER_DETAILS_SUCCESS = 'ORDER_DETAILS_SUCCESS'
export const ORDER_DETAILS_FAIL = 'ORDER_DETAILS_FAIL'
```

django url path:

```
path('<str:pk>/', views.getOrderById, name='user-order'),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfrJG.png)

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue with change "order.shippingAddress" to "order.ShippingAddress", I just check out the file models.py in the base folder and find out the exact name that is ShippingAddress, then try to run makemigrations and migrate. hope it's help.